# TableView keeps empty after using NSFetchedResultsController

Tags: ios, core-data, tableview, nsfetchedresultscontroller

I've tried to use NSFetchedResultsController in order to display sections to my tableView. But now my tableView keeps empty.

```
 @property (nonatomic,strong) NSManagedObjectContext* managedObjectContext;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSFetchedResultsController *fetchedResultsController;


- (NSManagedObjectContext *)managedObjectContext
{
    NSManagedObjectContext *context = nil;
    id delegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    if ([delegate performSelector:@selector(managedObjectContext)]) {
        context = [delegate managedObjectContext];
    }
    return context;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
   self.fetchedResultsController = nil;
    self.fetchedResultsController.delegate = nil;

}


- (NSFetchedResultsController *)fetchedResultsController {

    if (_fetchedResultsController != nil) {
        return _fetchedResultsController;
    }

    NSManagedObjectContext *managedObjectContext = [self managedObjectContext];


    // Create and configure a fetch request with the plant entity.
    NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
    NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Travel" inManagedObjectContext:managedObjectContext];
    [fetchRequest setEntity:entity];

    // Create the sort descriptors array.
    NSSortDescriptor *nameDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"name" ascending:YES];
    NSArray *sortDescriptors = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:nameDescriptor, nil];
    [fetchRequest setSortDescriptors:sortDescriptors];

    // Create and initialize the fetch results controller.
    NSFetchedResultsController *aFetchedResultsController = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:fetchRequest managedObjectContext:managedObjectContext sectionNameKeyPath:@"country" cacheName:@"country"];
    self.fetchedResultsController = aFetchedResultsController;
    _fetchedResultsController.delegate = self;

    return _fetchedResultsController;
}


- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    // Return the number of sections.
    return [[self.fetchedResultsController sections] count];
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    id <NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo> sectionInfo = [self.fetchedResultsController sections][section];
    return [sectionInfo numberOfObjects];
}


- (NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section { return @""; }
```

I followed a tutorial but the tableView is empty now. My tableView worked before fine (with coreData).
Maybe someone knows an answer to my question. Thanks.

Comment: you should call [self fetchedResultsController] not [self.fetchedResultsController]. You set the latter one to nil in viewDidLoad.

Comment: @theaob Look at his code, he is lazily loading it in the accessor.

Comment: @user2650439  Please can you tell me what tutorial you used so I can recommend people avoid it.

Comment: @Abizern [self fetchedResultsController] is never called. So the property never gets inited.

Comment: what do you think self.fetchedResultsController resolves to?

Comment: the property and the method are named same.

Comment: Hm...my code seems to be a lot of mess...But can anyone give me a link to a tutorial, which shows just how to section a tableView using coreData by one attribute of the entity

Comment: You can try this: http://www.raywenderlich.com/999/core-data-tutorial-for-ios-how-to-use-nsfetchedresultscontroller

Answer (score 2):

You appear to have forgotten to do this after constructing your `NSFetchedResultsController`:

```
NSError *error;
BOOL success = [_fetchedResultsController performFetch:&error];
```